# How to revert 3 git commits

Tags: git, git-revert

I need to go back 3 commits on master from the repo. My hash codes look like ( newest to oldest):

```
0cf2ebda - broken, okay to delete
9344b597 - broken, okay to delete
8f7aaea8 - broken, okay to delete
aa048e18 - this is good
```

After reading about revert, rebase, etc. it still is not clear to me. It seems like revert is only good for removing one commit only. And people have said to never use rebase.

How can I get back to **aa048e18**? I have already recovered any changes from the other commits on another branch.

Comment: I wish I could find the duplicate you refer to.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "forget" the 3 revisions as if they had never existed on your branch, then **git reset --hard aa048e18**.